# why can't i get All text within this xpath in this page?

Tags: c#, xml, html-agility-pack, innertext

here is the url and xpath .
url : http://product.dangdang.com/product.aspx?product_id=21026883&ref=book-01-E1
xpath:  //span[@class='detail_all']

doc.SelectSingleNode(xpath).innertext  just can't get **ALL** innertext with this xpath !

why ?

how can i fix this ?

thx !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `SelectSingleNode`, as it will only return the first `span` or node if you want.

You have to iterate over `doc.SelectNodes` and concatenate your results.

Comment: maybe you're right, but in my case , these text which i said can't get is loaded by javascript , they're not in the page source !

Comment: Then you need to use a different approach. Evaluating javascript in order to produce a proper DOM is non-trivial, and not possible with Html Agility Pack. Check this SO question for more insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570993/select-elements-added-to-the-dom-by-a-script

Comment: thanks, i've solved it . make an ajax to the url that js referd , then deserialize json ....